# Default params, async await, document.evaluate.Не работает scope в функции завязанной на document.evaluate.Подскажите как пофиксить

Tags: javascript

```
const defaultIntervalStepValue = 10; 
const defaultIndividualTimeoutValue = 4000; 

async function searchForElementByXPath(xpath, 
  step_value = defaultIntervalStepValue,
  timeout_value = defaultIndividualTimeoutValue,
  search_scope = document, 
  single_search = false) {

  var step, timeout;

  
  if (single_search) {
    let element = document.evaluate(
      xpath,
      search_scope,
      null,
      XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
      null
    ).singleNodeValue;

    
    return element;
  } else {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      step = setInterval(() => {
        let element = document.evaluate(
          xpath,
          search_scope,
          null,
          XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
          null
        ).singleNodeValue;
        if (element !== null && element !== undefined) {
          clearInterval(step);
          if (timeout_value > 0) clearTimeout(timeout);
          resolve(element);
        }
      }, step_value);

      if (timeout_value > 0) {
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          clearInterval(step);
          reject(`Timed out while searching for element with XPath: ${xpath}`);
        }, timeout_value);
      }
    });
  }
}



async function getTitle() {
  let g = await searchForElementByXPath(xpath=`//div[span[.='something']]`);
  console.log(g);

  let h = await searchForElementByXPath(xpath=`//span`, search_scope = g);
  console.log(h);
}

getTitle();
```

Comment: _«Не работает scope»_ - эм... чиво?)) В каком смысле "не работает", как это проявляется, какая работа ожидается?

Comment: Сори не не точность, в document.evaluate второй параметр search_scope, он должен передаваться из параметра функции при вызове(если он не указан,то по умолчанию document).Проблема в том, что этот search_scope не передается и используется тот, что по умолчанию

Comment: Вероятно, из-за того что мясо со строковым литералом: `'//div[span[.=\'something']]'` - попробуй вторую кавычку заэкранировать, ту что после `something` :) Кстати, присваивание необъявленной глобальной переменной `xpath` (в выражении первого аргумента) будет приводить к ошибке в strict режиме выполнения...

Comment: К сожалению, не из-за кавычек

Comment: А, ну так у тебя второй аргумент вызова попадает в `step_value`, а `search_scope === undefined` - вот и используется дефолтное значение `document`. Если надеешься что по записи вида `search_scope = g` интерпретатор догадается что ты хочешь в четвертый позиционный параметр передать значение, то напрасно: JS так не работает (фактически, такой записью ты присваиваешь значение глобальной переменной, и затем ее значение передаешь вторым аргументом). Вообще в JS нет такой фичи как именованные параметры, поддерживаются только позиционные... можно принимать параметром объект, если подобное требуется.

Comment: Я правильно понял нужно поменять местами step_value и search_scope?
если так,то всё равно почему-то не работает

Answer (score 1):

Вместо этой строки:

```js
let h = await searchForElementByXPath(xpath=`//span`, search_scope = g);
```

придётся писать так, если хотите, чтобы у второго и третьего аргументов были значения по умолчанию:

```js
let h = await searchForElementByXPath(xpath=`//span`, undefined, undefined,  g);
```

Вы не можете в вызове функции присвоить значение сразу четвёртому аргументу по его имени, пропустив предыдущие.

Чтобы не было таких казусов, нужно или менять порядок параметров в объявлении функции, помещая вперёд те, которые чаще будут задаваться, или передавать все аргументы как ключи одного объекта.

Ваш текущий код делает не то, что вы думаете: он создаёт глобальную переменную `search_scope`, присваивает ей значение `g` и передаёт его в качестве второго параметра, а в нём функция ждёт `step_value`, поэтому всё перепутывается.

Answer (score 0):

Решение - задаем аргументы функции таким образом:

```
async function searchForElementByXPath({
  xpath, 
  step_value = defaultIntervalStepValue,
  timeout_value = defaultIndividualTimeoutValue,
  search_scope = document, 
  single_search = false
} = {})
```

И вызываем функцию так

```
await searchForElementByXPath({
      xpath : 'random xpath',
      timeout_value : 4000
    });
```